# Mysql Query Except and Where

Tags: mysql, where-clause, except

I have the follow query selecting stuff from a database:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories order by id desc EXCEPT 
             WHERE id = $post_id") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

What I want to do is select all the columns in the "category" table, order them by id descending except where the column  "id" equals the variable $post_id.

However, this does not work. I'm relatively new to this sort of stuff so could you guys give me a pointer in the right direction? I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id != $post_id
order by id desc 

/* except = not equal */
```